# Iterate through two columns to see if there is a substring present in a list, add it to a third column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of strings:

```
YOUTUBE = ['bumper youtube','yt trueview', 'youtube trueview','yt pre-roll','youtube pre-roll','yt bumper','youtube bumper' ,'bumper','yt preferred pre-roll','youtube preferred pre-roll', 'YT preferred bumper', 'youtube preferred bumper', 'YT masthead', 'youtube masthead', 'trueview youtube','trueview']
```

I also have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Line Item                                      |    Insertion Order            | Creative Size           
_____________________________________________________________________
ch video cross ff bumper youtube mk it mb      | gen 20 youtube                | Unknown    
moisturizerbody trueview ym21998557 yt youtube | trueview ym21998557 yt youtube| Unknown
useless string                                 | dunno                         | Unknown
012020 trueview ym21978191 yt youtube bumper   | davena bumper youtube 24      | Unknown
```

I have to iterate both on the column Insertion Order and Creative Size.
If any value in the list YOUTUBE is in the column Line Item or Insertion Order, the string, which is in the list ,should be inserted in Creative Size at the corresponding line. If there is more than one possible match, any matched string is ok.
How can I do it? It's ok to import Regex if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with joined both strings columns by `+` with `\b\b` for words boundaries:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in YOUTUBE)
df['new'] = (df['Line Item'] + ' ' + df['Insertion Order']).str.findall(pat).str.join(', ')

print (df)
                                        Line Item  \
0       ch video cross ff bumper youtube mk it mb   
1  moisturizerbody trueview ym21998557 yt youtube   
2                                  useless string   
3    012020 trueview ym21978191 yt youtube bumper   

                  Insertion Order Creative Size                         new  
0                  gen 20 youtube       Unknown            [bumper youtube]  
1  trueview ym21998557 yt youtube       Unknown                  [trueview]  
2                           dunno       Unknown                          []  
3        davena bumper youtube 24       Unknown  [trueview, bumper youtube]
```

If nees joined strings by `,` add [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in YOUTUBE)
df['new'] = df['Line Item'].add(df['Insertion Order']).str.findall(pat).str.join(', ')

print (df)
                                        Line Item  \
0       ch video cross ff bumper youtube mk it mb   
1  moisturizerbody trueview ym21998557 yt youtube   
2                                  useless string   
3    012020 trueview ym21978191 yt youtube bumper   

                  Insertion Order Creative Size                       new  
0                  gen 20 youtube       Unknown            bumper youtube  
1  trueview ym21998557 yt youtube       Unknown                  trueview  
2                           dunno       Unknown                            
3        davena bumper youtube 24       Unknown  trueview, bumper youtube
```

Comment: For some reason it does not work, may be due to SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead ?

Comment: What is your complete code? Is possible edit question?

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is simple and should work. The last match (in either 'Line Item' or 'Insertion Order' columns) will override any previous matches (in these 2 columns) and this string is the string you will see in the 'Creative Size' column for each row. df_ex is the name of the example DataFrame.

```
for idx,row in df_ex.iterrows():
    for string in YOUTUBE:
        if (string in row['Line Item']) or (string in row['Insertion Order']): # can also use regex here
            df_ex.loc[idx, 'Creative Size'] = string
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to improve your answer by adding a short explanation of the crucial part. For future readers it's far more interesting to see explained *why* this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index where there is a match and copy that match to the column of interest like in this example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Line Item": ['nope', 'nope', 'yep1!'],"Insertion Order": ['nope', 'yep2!', 'nope'], "Creative Size": ['', '', '']})
youtube = ['foo', 'bar', 'yep1!', 'yep2!']

for col in data.columns:
    ind = data.loc[data[col].isin(youtube)].index
    data['Creative Size'].iloc[ind] = data[col].iloc[ind]

data
```

output:
[image]